# Angular Single Page App with JSON Object Depending on the Selection of Another

Tags: angularjs, json, nested-forms, angular-material, angularjs-ng-form

I am putting together a questionnaire. Each question has three options to choose from. Each object containing the question has another object named 'dependsOn'. 
An example would be that if "Yes" is selected on question 1 then the following two questions will show, otherwise they will be skipped.
I appreciate any help, ideas, suggestions you may have for this small app.
Here is a CodePen I put together: [my codepen](http://codepen.io/ChidoYo/pen/RagRqd?editors=1010)

```
<div class="main" ng-app="MyApp">

<div ng-controller="AppCtrl as q">

<h1>{{ q.title }}</h1>

<form name="collection" novalidate>

    <div class="questionnaire">

        <div class="questions">

            <div class="question" ng-repeat="question in q.questions" ng-show="question.hrsQuestionOrderNumber === q.currentQuestion">
                <h2>Question {{ question.hrsQuestionOrderNumber }} <span>of {{ q.questions.length }}</span></h2>
                <p>
                    {{ question.descriptionLong }}
                </p>

                <ng-form name="subForm{{question.questionID}}" class="options">
                    <md-radio-group ng-model="question.hrsAnswerId" ng-change="q.watchForm(subForm{{ q.currentQuestion }})" required>
                      <md-radio-button ng-repeat="option in question.choiceModels" ng-value="option.description" required>
                        {{ option.description }}
                      </md-radio-button>
                    </md-radio-group>
                </ng-form>
            </div>

        </div>

        <nav class="clearfix">
          <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="q.questionChange('prev')" ng-disabled="q.prev">Previous</md-button>
          <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="q.questionChange('next')" ng-disabled="q.next">Next</md-button>
        </nav>
    </div>

</form>
```

Angular code:

```
angular
.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function($timeout, $scope) {

const context = this;

context.title = 'Questionnaire with Questions Depending on Choices';
context.currentQuestion = 1;
context.next = true;
context.prev = true;
context.nextButton = true;

context.form = $scope.collection;

function disableButton () {

    if (context.currentQuestion === 1) {
        context.prev = true;
        context.next = false;
    } else {
        context.prev = false;
        context.next = false;
    }
};

context.questionChange = function (go) {

    if (go === 'prev') {
        context.currentQuestion = context.currentQuestion - 1;
    }

    if (go === 'next') {

        context.currentQuestion = context.currentQuestion + 1;

        $timeout(function () {
            context.next = true;
        });
    }

    disableButton();
};

context.watchForm = function (currentForm) {

  if (currentForm.$invalid === false) {

    if (context.currentQuestion !== context.questions.length) {
      context.next = false;
    }
  } else {
    console.log('form NOT in scope');
  }

};

context.questions = [
            {
              "questionID": 1,
              "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 1,
              "descriptionLong": "Do you collect money from anyone (students, employees, or other sources)?",
              "choiceModels": [
                {
                  "description": "Yes",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "No",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "None / Not applicable",
                  "answerId": 3
                }
              ],
              "dependsOn": null
            },
            {
              "questionID": 2,
              "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 2,
              "descriptionLong": "Are pre-numbered receipts given to the person paying money? If individual receipts are not given, do you use an approved PBO/S&I collection document?",
              "choiceModels": [
                {
                  "description": "Yes",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "No",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "None / Not applicable",
                  "answerId": 3
                }
              ],
              "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 1,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "questionID": 3,
              "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 3,
              "descriptionLong": "Do cash receipts or logs contain sufficient detail to accurately describe the nature of the transaction?",
              "choiceModels": [
                {
                  "description": "Yes",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "No",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "None / Not applicable",
                  "answerId": 3
                }
              ],
              "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 1,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "questionID": 4,
              "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 4,
              "descriptionLong": "Do receipts or logs identify individuals and not groups of individuals (such as a class)?",
              "choiceModels": [
                {
                  "description": "Yes",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "No",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "None / Not applicable",
                  "answerId": 3
                }
              ],
              "dependsOn": null
            },
            {
              "questionID": 5,
              "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 5,
              "descriptionLong": "For money collected, is it always deposited and never used for purchases?",
              "choiceModels": [
                {
                  "description": "Yes",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "No",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "None / Not applicable",
                  "answerId": 3
                }
              ],
              "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 4,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "questionID": 6,
              "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 6,
              "descriptionLong": "For money not yet deposited, is it kept in a secure location?",
              "choiceModels": [
                {
                  "description": "Yes",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "No",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "None / Not applicable",
                  "answerId": 3
                }
              ],
              "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 4,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1
              }
            },
            {
              "questionID": 7,
              "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 7,
              "descriptionLong": "Do you keep a file of original deposit documentation—including cash receipts or logs—together?",
              "choiceModels": [
                {
                  "description": "Yes",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "No",
                  "answerId": 1
                },
                {
                  "description": "None / Not applicable",
                  "answerId": 3
                }
              ],
              "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 4,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1
              }
            }
          ];

})
.config(function($mdIconProvider) {
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to loop through the question and evaluate wether the question depended on the answer selected. This enabled some questions to be skipped based on the answer selected. 
Here is my CodePen: [My CodePend](http://codepen.io/ChidoYo/pen/RagRqd)

```
angular
.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($timeout, $scope, $filter) {

    const context = this;

    context.title = 'Questions Depending on Choices';
    context.heading = 'Questionnaire';
    context.currentQuestion = 1;
    context.next = true;
    context.prev = true;
    context.nextButton = true;

    function disableButton() {

        if (context.currentQuestion === 1) {
            context.prev = true;
            context.next = false;
        } else {
            context.prev = false;
            context.next = false;
        }
    };

    context.questionChange = function(go) {

        if (go === 'prev') {

            context.currentQuestion = context.currentQuestion - 1;
            //Go to the prev (in order) that has an selectedAnswer
            var prevQuestions = $filter("filter")(context.questions, { "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": context.currentQuestion });
            if (!prevQuestions[0].hrsAnswerId) {
                context.questionChange(go);
            }
        }

        if (go === 'next') {
            //in order - check the dependsOn for Q&a required

            context.currentQuestion = context.currentQuestion + 1;
            var nextQuestions = $filter("filter")(context.questions, { "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": context.currentQuestion });
            if (nextQuestions.length > 0) {
                var dependsOn = nextQuestions[0].dependsOn;
                if (dependsOn) {
                    var dependentQuestions = $filter("filter")(context.questions, { "questionID": dependsOn.hrsQuestionLink });
                    if (dependentQuestions[0].hrsAnswerId !== dependsOn.hrsAnswerId) {
                        context.questionChange(go);
                    }
                }
            }

            $timeout(function () {
                context.next = true;
            });
        }

        disableButton();
    };

    context.watchForm = function(currentForm) {

        if (currentForm.$invalid === false) {

            if (context.currentQuestion !== context.questions.length) {
                context.next = false;
            }
        } else {
            console.log('form NOT in scope');
        }

    };



    context.questions = [
        {
            "questionID": 1533,
            "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 1,
            "descriptionLong": "Do you collect money from anyone (students, employees, or other sources)?",
            "choiceModels": [
                {
                    "description": "Yes",
                    "answerId": 1000
                },
                {
                    "description": "No",
                    "answerId": 1001
                },
                {
                    "description": "None / Not applicable",
                    "answerId": 1148
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": null
        },
        {
            "questionID": 1534,
            "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 2,
            "descriptionLong": "Are pre-numbered receipts given to the person paying money? If individual receipts are not given, do you use an approved PBO/S&I collection document?",
            "choiceModels": [
                {
                    "description": "Yes",
                    "answerId": 1000
                },
                {
                    "description": "No",
                    "answerId": 1001
                },
                {
                    "description": "None / Not applicable",
                    "answerId": 1148
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 1533,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1000
            }
        },
        {
            "questionID": 1535,
            "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 3,
            "descriptionLong": "Do cash receipts or logs contain sufficient detail to accurately describe the nature of the transaction?",
            "choiceModels": [
                {
                    "description": "Yes",
                    "answerId": 1000
                },
                {
                    "description": "No",
                    "answerId": 1001
                },
                {
                    "description": "None / Not applicable",
                    "answerId": 1148
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 1533,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1000
            }
        },
        {
            "questionID": 1536,
            "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 4,
            "descriptionLong": "Do receipts or logs identify individuals and not groups of individuals (such as a class)?",
            "choiceModels": [
                {
                    "description": "Yes",
                    "answerId": 1000
                },
                {
                    "description": "No",
                    "answerId": 1001
                },
                {
                    "description": "None / Not applicable",
                    "answerId": 1148
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": null
        },
        {
            "questionID": 1537,
            "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 5,
            "descriptionLong": "For money collected, is it always deposited and never used for purchases?",
            "choiceModels": [
                {
                    "description": "Yes",
                    "answerId": 1000
                },
                {
                    "description": "No",
                    "answerId": 1001
                },
                {
                    "description": "None / Not applicable",
                    "answerId": 1148
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 1536,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1000
            }
        },
        {
            "questionID": 1538,
            "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 6,
            "descriptionLong": "For money not yet deposited, is it kept in a secure location?",
            "choiceModels": [
                {
                    "description": "Yes",
                    "answerId": 1000
                },
                {
                    "description": "No",
                    "answerId": 1001
                },
                {
                    "description": "None / Not applicable",
                    "answerId": 1148
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 1536,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1000
            }
        },
        {
            "questionID": 1539,
            "hrsQuestionOrderNumber": 7,
            "descriptionLong": "Do you keep a file of original deposit documentation—including cash receipts or logs—together?",
            "choiceModels": [
                {
                    "description": "Yes",
                    "answerId": 1000
                },
                {
                    "description": "No",
                    "answerId": 1001
                },
                {
                    "description": "None / Not applicable",
                    "answerId": 1148
                }
            ],
            "dependsOn": {
                "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                "hrsQuestionLink": 1536,
                "hrsAnswerId": 1000
            }
        }
    ];

})
.config(function($mdIconProvider) {
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is your problem?

1. Create object that will contain number of question as a key and answer index as a value

   {'1': 1, '2': 0, ...}
2. After every answer you just walk through array of questions and select next question in depends of what user chosen.

Comment: The data is in context.questions. Each question has a dependsOn object and sometimes it is null and in other cases it shows 
                  "dependsOn": {
                    "hrsQuestionId": 0,
                    "hrsQuestionLink": 1,
                    "hrsAnswerId": 1
                  }
This means that this question depends on user selecting hrsAnswer 1 in question 1. I hope that makes sense. I'm a beginner to this.

Comment: Right. In walk cycle you can check if dependsOn === null if so then we can just choose this question as a next.
if dependsOn !== null then you just need to check answer in answers array.